# Catching ElasticSearch exceptions when making HTTP POST requests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch `7.2.0`. I use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class to make `POST` requests to my ElasticSearch server:

```
private const string Host = "http://127.0.0.1";
private const int Port = 9200;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Receive(string jsonPostContents)
{
    try
    {
        return await this.httpClient.PostAsync($"{Host}:{Port}/_bulk?pipeline=ParseDuration", 
                                               new StringContent(jsonPostContents, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType: MimeTypes.Json));
    }

    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        StringContent responseString = new StringContent($"Exception encountered: {exception.Message}.\n" +
                                                         $"Inner exception: {exception.InnerException?.Message}\n" +
                                                         $"Stack trace: {exception.StackTrace}");

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) { Content = responseString };
    }
}
```

In the `cmd.exe` window in which I am running ElasticSearch, the following error message is printed:

```
[2019-09-17T11:45:14,569][DEBUG][o.e.a.b.TransportBulkAction] [MyServer] failed to execute pipeline [ParseDuration] for document [testindex/_doc/5c91f6e0-b72f-48b2-8430-ad76a640347a]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pipeline with id [ParseDuration] does not exist
        at org.elasticsearch.ingest.IngestService$4.doRun(IngestService.java:408) [elasticsearch-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:758) [elasticsearch-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) [?:?]
```

However, instead of returning an HTTP error response, the `Receive(string jsonPostContents)` method returns an `OK` response instead (with HTTP status code `200`).

How can I ensure that all ElasticSearch exceptions are reliably captured?

Comment: Did you think about using [official .Net client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net)? You could get pretty reliable error handling for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bulk API returns error only if there were connectivity problems, otherwise returns 200.

You should check the response from the bulk. If there was a single error in the bulk, the response it will look like:

```
{
   "took": x,
   "errors": true,
   "items":[
   //element i: shows what happened with the item i from bulk
   ]
}
```